# How to handle WebElement Dropdown whose tag starts with <Span>?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Script is selecting country element then entering Text in Search field as "India" which shows 2 values in search result . I am unable to select displayed field value ?

Test Case :-
1. Navigate to Country ( Please select )
2. Search box is displayed - Example Sendkeys "India" 
3. List of Countries displayed

**HTML Code for Country Element ( Please select )**

[image]

**HTML Code for Search text box in dropdown** 
[image]

//Dropdown & Search by Text India

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='ojChoiceId_country_selected']")).click();
    System.out.println("You are able to click on Dropdown");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"oj-listbox-drop\"]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("United States");
```

Comment: can you share your drop down image?

Comment: or share your DOM image

Comment: have shared the DOM Image

Comment: It is an autocomplete text box

Comment: these drop down options are under which tag?

Comment: Inspect the list of countries, is it some dynamic web element that opens when you expand the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also got a autocomplete text box options, so for that i have just created the method which used to control it, may this help you please modify it with your use:-

```
public static void selectAutoSearchText(By selectBoxElement,By textBoxElement, By dropdownElement, String textValue, String matchingValue, WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) throws InterruptedException
    {       
        try {
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(selectBoxElement)).click();

            WebElement searchBox= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(textBoxElement));
            searchBox.sendKeys(textValue);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement waitElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(dropdownElement));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            List<WebElement> dropdownList= waitElement.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            //System.out.println(dropdownList);
            //System.out.println(dropdownList.size());
            for(WebElement listElement :dropdownList)
            {
                //System.out.println(listElement.getText());
                if(listElement.getText().equals(matchingValue))
                {
                    listElement.click();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have used both `Explicit Wait` and `Thread.sleep` just because by drop down options value loaded after some time, so in some cases it failed to select options so i used the thread.sleep to reduce it.

In this you just need to pass the Xpath of these values and text which you will enter and matching value is for select that country name on which you want click for select that option.

I have used tag name `<tr>` you can change it according to your options tag because it can be `Button` or `Span` tag also.